# Mocked DbContext update method error - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have a problem with a unit test method. I am testing a controller action which uses a repository that has a mocked DbContext object provided.

I am getting the error specified in the title, however since the DbContext is a mocked (moq) object I do not understand why does it not work.

The method that I am testing is

```
  public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            this.DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            this.Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified; //here the error is thrown
        }
```

Repository is created as follows (the .ReturnsDbSet() comes from [here](http://codethug.com/2015/03/20/mocking-dbset/))

```
var enumerable = new List<User>();
// ... populate the mocks list
 var mockedContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
 mockedContext.Setup(c => c.Users).ReturnsDbSet(enumerable);
 mockedContext.Setup(c => c.Set<User>()).ReturnsDbSet(enumerable);
 var repo = new Mock<IRepository<User>>();           
 return new Repository<User>(mockedContext.Object, this.logger);
```

A repository fragment:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> :  IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
        protected internal MyDbContext Context;
        protected internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
        public Repository(MyDbContext context)
        {
            this.Context = context;
            this.DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.DbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            return query;
        }
```

And the dbContext below. The initializer only calls the Seed method and adds some boilerplate entities for development. (DropCreateIfModelChanges)

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("name=MyDatabaseConnection")
        {

            Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MybInitializer());

        }

        public virtual DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    }
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Show definition of your DbContext. most probably when initialized it is trying to connect to a real database which will fail since no connection string probably exists

Comment: `base("name=MyDatabaseConnection")` it is trying to connect to the database. that is the cause. Abstract the db access so that it can be mocked without tightly coupled implementation concerns

Comment: @Nkosi - ok, but I have tens of tests that use the very same repository object and work fine - for example, I am testing the 'Insert' method as well and I have no errors there...

Comment: I can only comment based on what is shown in question. When accessing db context members that access database it will try to connect.

Comment: @Nkosi - could it be that it only happens when ` this.Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;` is called? I.e. as long as the test does not invoke directly any of the Context properties or methods, it works fine?

Comment: That is an accurate assessment. This is why I tend to abstract data access and also try to avoid unit testing `DbContext` Test code you control.

Comment: @Nkosi - Right... What I don't understand is that I am not using the DbContext - I am providing a Mocked object...

Comment: if you are doing a mock of dbcontext you are using the object. just one derived from it which means it still encapsulates all its original functionality. You are mocking an implementation concern. not an abstraction. So you are basically providing a stub

Comment: @Nkosi - right... I thought thats the proper way. Could you maybe provide an example of how this should be done?

Comment: Why are even going through all if this. Is the controller is using the repository it should be using the abstraction anyway so implementation concerns like DbContext should not even be a factor. Are you testing the controller or the repository?

Comment: @Nkosi - isn't the generic repository already an abstraction from the dbcontext?
The reason I am not using a mock of IRepository is that I don't want to setup the gets and sets methods of it - especially with the linq queries etc. I just want to provide some mock data and access it in the controller.

Comment: To solve this you need to create an interface `IDbContext` and have your MyDbContext implement it and your repository should depend on the interface. And in tests you need to create mock of interface .

Comment: I think you need to set the connection string in the web.config of the unit test project itself.

Comment: Today I got this error, so I removed the line who I define a state and it started works for me (`Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Added`)